# Difference between SQL joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, crystal-reports

When I change this:

```
FROM "Server"."dbo"."SalesTable" "SalesTable"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."ItemTable" "ItemTable" 
ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey"="SalesTable"."ItemKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."ItemClassTable" "ItemClassTable"
ON "ItemTable"."ItemClassKey" = "ItemClassTable"."ItemClassKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."ItemDescriptionTable" "ItemDescriptionTable" 
ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey"="ItemDescriptionTable"."ItemKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."timSalesProdLine" "timSalesProdLine" 
ON "ItemTable"."SalesLineKey"="timSalesProdLine"."SalesLineKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."InventoryTable" "InventoryTable"  
ON "ItemTable"."ItemKey" = "InventoryTable"."ItemKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."AccountTable" "AccountTable" 
ON "InventoryTable"."SalesAcctKey"="AccountTable"."GLAcctKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."CustomerTable" "CustomerTable"
ON "CustomerTable"."CustKey" = "SalesTable"."CustKey"
```

To this:

```
FROM "Server"."dbo"."SalesTable" "SalesTable"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."itemTable" "itemTable" 
ON "itemTable"."ItemKey"="SalesTable"."ItemKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."itemClassTable" "itemClassTable"
ON "itemTable"."ItemClassKey" = "itemClassTable"."ItemClassKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."ItemDescriptionTable" "ItemDescriptionTable" 
ON "itemTable"."ItemKey"="ItemDescriptionTable"."ItemKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."timSalesProdLine" "timSalesProdLine" 
ON "itemTable"."SalesLineKey"="timSalesProdLine"."SalesLineKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."inventoryTable" "inventoryTable"
ON "SalesTable"."WarehouseKey" = "inventoryTable"."WarehouseKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."AccountTable" "AccountTable" 
ON "inventoryTable"."SalesAcctKey"="AccountTable"."GLAcctKey"

INNER JOIN "Server"."dbo"."CustomerTable" "CustomerTable"
ON "CustomerTable"."CustKey" = "SalesTable"."CustKey"
```

I get an error message.

I am using an ODBC connection via Excel and the error message is: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).] General network error. Check your network documentation."

When I try to run through a command in Crystal Reports, the error message is the same except it ends with: "[Database Ventor Code: 11]".

Only change is join 5 where I attempt to link the tables with "WarehouseKey".

What can I do differently?

I omitted the rest of my query because it's the same in both scenarios. Of course, if needed, I can add via edit.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942861/en-us

Comment: Probably you need a hotfix

Comment: Can you try and execute the query in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) - does it error? What is the datatype of WarehouseKey (in both tables?)

Comment: @sqluser that's getting a little beyond my paygrade. IT isn't real thrilled with me simply using SQL in the first place.

Comment: @RhysJones don't have access to SSMS that I can see. WarehouseKey is INT